# ggplot2: drawing a line between two values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~group,   ~value,   ~ci_low,  ~ci_upper,  
  "group1", 0.0577434,  0.0567665,    0.0587203,
  "group2", 0.0941233,  0.0801769,    0.1080698)
```

I want to plot the column "value" as a point and then a dashed line that goes "under" which minimum point is ci_low and high point is ci_upper.

So far I have this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(group, value)) +
  geom_point(size = 4)
```

And I want something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have control over the line ends, use `geom_segment`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(group, value)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = group, y = ci_low, yend = ci_upper), color = "red", size = 2, lineend = "round") +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

If square line ends are OK, use `geom_linerange`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(group, value)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = ci_low, ymax = ci_upper), color = "red", size = 2) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=group, y=value)) + 
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=ci_low, ymax=ci_upper))
```